# Java Apache-POI XWPF how to copy or output bitmaps?

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

Done a bit of research on this and it seems there have been bugs relating to this in the past, I'm unsure if they're solved in the lastest version.

I'm reading a docx template, doing a few mods and outputting it. I'm copying all elements of the document fine except for bitmaps, a marker appears where the bitmap should be containing the text, "this image cannot currently be displayed". I've had a few goes at doing it.

What is the recommended way of copying a bitmap from one document to another?

I can get images as follows:

> List piclist = template.getAllPictures();
>
> XWPFPictureData picture = (XWPFPictureData)piclist.get(i);

But I'm not sure how to copy that into my new document.

I've tried a test adding a single bitmap from a file and this code creates a Word document that gives an error and fails to load into Word:

> InputStream pic = new FileInputStream("filename.gif");
>
> outputDoc.addPictureData(pic, outputDoc.PICTURE_TYPE_GIF);

Any help greatly appreciated. Very impressed generally with Apache-POI.

Comment: That doesn't look quite right, as it doesn't associate the picture with anywhere in the document. What happens if you try the approach shown in [TestXWPFRun.testAddPicture()](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/testcases/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/TestXWPFRun.java)?

Answer (score 2):

Quite a late answer, but who knows..
If you want to copy one document's pictures to another, try the following:

```
public void copyAllImages( XWPFDocument sourceDocument, XWPFDocument targetDocument ) {
    Map<String, Integer> extractedImages = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    XWPFPictureData pictureData = null;

    // 1. Writing all found images to the disk (to the same folder as your source document)
    for ( XWPFParagraph par : sourceDocument.getParagraphs() ) {
        for ( XWPFRun run : par.getRuns() ) {
            for ( XWPFPicture picture : run.getEmbeddedPictures() ) {
                pictureData = picture.getPictureData();
                byte[] img = pictureData.getData();
                String fileName = pictureData.getFileName();
                int imageFormat = pictureData.getPictureType();
                writeByteArrayToFile( img, fileName );
                extractedImages.put( fileName, imageFormat );
            }
        }
    }

    // 2. Writing images from the disk to the final document,
    // creating 1 new paragraph with 1 run for each image.
    for ( String imageFileName : extractedImages.keySet() ) {
        XWPFParagraph newParagraph = targetDocument.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun newRun = newParagraph.createRun();
        copyImageToRun( imageFileName, newRun, extractedImages.get( imageFileName ) );
    }
}

private static void writeByteArrayToFile( byte[] byteArray, String fileName ) {
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream( new File( fileName ) );
        out.write( byteArray );
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            out.close();
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void copyImageToRun( String imageFileName, XWPFRun run, int format ) {
    run.setText( imageFileName );
    run.addBreak();

    try {
        run.addPicture( new FileInputStream( imageFileName ), format, imageFileName,
                Units.toEMU( 200 ), Units.toEMU( 200 ) ); // 200x200 pixels

    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    run.addBreak( BreakType.PAGE );
}
```

So you just two XWPFDocument objects, pass them to the first function (copyAllImages), and then save those documents using `document.write(out)` as usual.
Depending on your needs, you can also add to step 1 code that will copy all content of your paragraphs (not just images). Probably one can skip writing images to the disk, inserting that pictureData directly into a newly created run. However, i didn't manage to make it work (images simply didn't appear). But using two-step approach, it finally gave a result.

Hope it helps!

P.S. now the question is which SIZE of image to use? For a moment I've seen only that `addPicture` function, which obliges you to pass width and height, which moreover can rescale your image. So we need some trick to extract the size (in pixels) that each image took in the original document (not nececcarily the original image size, as it can be rescaled by user).

Inspired from [here](https://code.google.com/p/zkpoi/source/browse/branches/zkpoi/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/SimpleImages.java?r=156).